# How can I get the index of an external JSON key or value using mustache.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, indexing, mustache

**I have this element I am looping through:**

```
{{#video}}
<li id="video{{type}}" onclick="FWDRL.show(\'{{lbid}}colTV\', {{index}});" data-url="{{url}}" data-poster-path="{{cover}}" data-thumbnail-path="{{cover}}" data-width="800" data-height="450"><h4><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i> {{type}}</h4><p class="description"></p></li>
{{/video}}
```

This grabs every instance of video in my external JSON file. However, I need to add the index value of these elements in the `{{index}}` tag. How can I do this?

Comment: mustache can't do that. you can use [my fork of mustache.js](https://github.com/rndme/mostache#user-content-index-mini-tag)'s `{INDEX}` mini-tag, or modify the JSON's object after parsing and add the index props to the data.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for the answer. I added the index props to the JSON data, but I felt like that was cheating the logic and wasn't as efficient as it could or should be; It works well though. This mostache.js looks pretty rad. I will check it out for sure. Thanks again!

Comment: adjusting incoming data is the only way to do a lot of stuff in mustache. you can clone it if you don't want to alter live values. i was in a situation i couldn't mod it when  i decided to fork mustache into mostache...

Answer (score 0):

One was is that, you need to define a property `index` in your JSON object

```
var counter = 1;
obj['index'] = function(){
    return counter++;
}
```